# ESRI ArcGis routing api extremely slow compared to other providers

Tags: javascript, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I'm implementing a wrapper that requests route information from different geospatial / gis api providers. Input is always two or more waypoints (latitude, longitude pairs).

It is not my goal to do a public benchmark or a comparison between different service providers. The problem is, it works pretty well with google maps, bing maps and here maps but requesting a route from esri route api takes forever.

For all providers, I tried to optimize settings as far as I could:
- Limiting the requested output to geometry, time and distance
- Using just default driving modes (such as car, no real time information...)

EDIT:

Request urls and response times (requested from Berlin, Europe) below. I executed the requests multiple times, even at different days and the times are almost the same. Coordinates are always Paris to Prague.

**ESRI**: 46,26 seconds(!)

`https://route.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/Route/NAServer/Route_World/solve?f=json&returnDirections=false&token=<my_api_token>&stops=2.3522,48.8566;14.4378,50.0755`

**BING**: 611 milliseconds

`https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Routes/Driving?key=<my_api_token>&ra=excludeItinerary,routePath&wp.1=48.8566,2.3522&wp.2=50.0755,14.4378`

**HERE**: 664 milliseconds

`http://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.0.17.0&app_id=<my_api_token>&mode=fastest%3Bcar&representation=display&waypoint0=geo!48.8566%2C2.3522&waypoint1=geo!50.0755%2C14.4378&jsoncallback=H.service.jsonp.handleResponse(5)`

**GOOGLE**: 92 milliseconds

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/DirectionsService.Route?5m4&1m3&1m2&1d48.8566&2d2.352200000000039&5m4&1m3&1m2&1d50.0755&2d14.437800000000038&6e0&12sen-US&23e1&callback=_xdc_._95pqrj&key=<my_api_token>
&token=117312`

Has anyone experienced the same? Do I miss any steps?

Update: Take a look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/298955/esri-arcgis-routing-api-extremely-slow-compared-to-other-providers for more information on how to improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the coordinates, you don't need to go through the widget, you can either use the API's RouteTask or just use the REST API directly (which is what the API uses under-the-hood).

Using the RouteTask in ArcGIS API for JavaScript:

- DevLab: https://developers.arcgis.com/labs/javascript/get-a-route-and-directions/
- API Reference: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-tasks-RouteTask.html
- Sample: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/tasks-route/index.html

Using the REST API:

- Overview: https://developers.arcgis.com/features/directions/
- DevLab:
  https://developers.arcgis.com/labs/rest/get-a-route-and-directions/
- API Reference: https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/network/api-reference/route-synchronous-service.htm